# How to deny user to access Webform in webconfig Ap.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-config

I am working on an application. It does not use Identity or Membership, has it own security system.

I have `role` Table where `roleid` is `PK` and roleName.
I have added administrative forms and want only user who are admin could view them.

if Membership were using then in RoleManager we could deny the users but how to do this in web config of current scenario.

Comment: Drop your "own security system" ? Or at least write your own RoleProvider for it. Mention the versions (.NET and ASP.NET) you use, it might matter.

Comment: .net 4.5 asp.net webforms

Answer (score 0):

If these forms are in controls do something like this possibly:

```
visible="<%# CheckEdit_Status() %>"
```